# How do I use return in a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, return, return-type

I have the following code:

```
const removeFromArray = function (xArray, xNumber) {
    
    for(let i = 0; i < xArray.length; i++) {
        if(xArray[i] === xNumber) {
            const index = xArray.indexOf(xNumber);
            const x = xArray.splice(index, 0);
        } else {
           console.log(xArray[i]);
        }
    }
};

removeFromArray([1, 11, 3, 4], 11);
```

The function takes *2 arguments*, the *array* and the *element* that you want to delete from the array.
In order to check if the function is working, we have to use *console.log*. I used it and it's working. Now I have to implement this in an exercise and I need to remove the console.log and use *return* instead.

I tried using `return` but it only returns the first number in the array, like so:
`return xArray[i];`

So how can I return the **whole array**?

```
removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 3); // should remove 3 and return [1,2,4]
```

Comment: Use `return xArray` to return the whole array.

Comment: You shouldn't return inside the loop. That will only test the first element, and return the original array if it's not the number you want to remove. The return statement should be after the loop is done.

Comment: So could you indicate where should I use return if it's not inside the loop? The function works because console.log is accurate. I just need to sort out the return value and that's it. Where do I write it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `return xArray` to return the entire array. Do this in the `if` block when you remove the element.

You need to specify length 1 in the `splice()` call to remove the element.

```js
const removeFromArray = function (xArray, xNumber) {
    
    for(let i = 0; i < xArray.length; i++) {
        if(xArray[i] === xNumber) {
            const index = xArray.indexOf(xNumber);
            xArray.splice(index, 1);
            return xArray;
        }
    }
};

console.log(removeFromArray([1, 11, 3, 4], 11));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use parameter value 1 of splice method. then return the array.hope it will work ex:

```
const removeFromArray = function (xArray, xNumber) {
    let filteredArray = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < xArray.length; i++) {
        if(xArray[i] === xNumber) {
            const index = xArray.indexOf(xNumber);
            const x = xArray.splice(index, 1);
            return x;
        } else {
           console.log(xArray[i]);
        }
    }
};

removeFromArray([1, 11, 3, 4], 11);
```